# SQL Server 2008 Function for Current Academic Year

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I work at a college in London and for some reason no one has added a function to call the current academic year within our SQL Server 2008 instance. I had done this successfully in the past on an Oracle server so I thought, how hard can it be, right?

It is only after a failed attempt of my own I realize it isn't as easy as I thought it would be.

My code so far:

```
USE [DashboardData]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [fea].[current_academic_year]
()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Result as int

IF Month(GETDATE())<8 
SET @Result= Year(GETDATE())-1 
ELSE 
SET @Result = Year(GETDATE())

RETURN @Result

END
```

Now, that looks simple enough to me - and it compiles. However, when I call the function in a simple query (on the same database):

```
Select fea.[current_academic_year]
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
> The multi-part
>   identifier "FEA.current_academic_year" could not be bound.

Having hardly ever used SQL Server before and after consulting Google, work-colleagues (who stare off into the distance) and former colleagues I am still without an answer. How and why is this happening?

Comment: You forgot the (), you are calling a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`Select fea.[current_academic_year]`

To this:

`SELECT [fea].[current_academic_year]()`

You are missing `()`, remember this is a scalar-valued function, not a column name.